# $\frac{x^5-y^5}{x-y}=p$,give what p ,the diophantine equation is solvable

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

for$$\frac{x^3-y^3}{x-y}=x^2+xy+y^2=p$$$p=6k+1$give p prime, On what conditions,the diophantine equation $$\frac{x^5-y^5}{x-y}=p$$ is solvable in integers.does it have a linear expression.for $$\frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}=p$$n =7,11,13...etc,is it easy to solve.and in what conditons ,it's solvable in $Z[i]$

Comment: OEIS: http://oeis.org/A002649 and $p\equiv 1 \pmod 5$

Answer (score 2):

Write out $$ x^4 + x^3 y + x^2 y^2 + x y^3 + y^4.  $$ Up to some large positive $N,$ the maximum number of possible values of this for $0 < y < x$ is no larger than $\sqrt N.$ As a result, it is not possible to describe the set of primes just by congruences. The quantitative aspect of Dirichlet's result on primes in arithmetic progressions is this: given fixed $a,b > 0,$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1,$ the number of primes in the progression $a t + b,$ up to $N,$ is asymptotically
$$  \frac{N}{\phi(a) \log N.}   $$  This is much, much larger than $\sqrt N.$