# What do we know about the class group of cyclotomic fields over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585245/fracx5-y5x-y-p-give-what-p-the-diophantine-equation-is-solvable), I am curious how one can characterize primes that splits completely in the Hilbert class field of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_q)$, where $q$ is a prime. Then I realize how much I don't know about this extension over $\mathbb{Q}$! I know this is too broad, but I'll be happy if someone can briefly write down what we can say about this extension in general. At the very least

> Is the extension $H/\mathbb{Q}$ abelian, if $H$ is the Hilbert class field of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_q)$, where $q$ is a prime? I guess it's generally not. If so, when is it abelian?

and

> What is the degree of $H/\mathbb{Q}$? What do we know about the ideal class groups of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_q)$?

Actually, I am not even sure what the right question to ask here is. A quick google search yields some relevant things, such as this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/968/what-is-the-hilbert-class-field-of-a-cyclotomic-field) and Franz Lemmermeyer's [papers.](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/publ/cycl1.pdf). They seem to say that:

1. We can't pin down the Hilbert class field of cyclotomic field unless it's imaginary quadratic or $\mathbb{Q}$ itself. But can we say anything about whether it's abelian, say?
2. There is a connection to the main theorem of Iwasawa theory. I know that this is too demanding, but if someone's willing to sketch a quick introduction to Iwasawa theory and how it connects to this problem here, I would be super grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

The extension $H/\mathbf Q$ is never abelian, unless $H=\mathbf Q(\zeta_q)$ (which happens for just a few values of $q$, since the class number of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_n)$ grows very fast).  Indeed, according to Kronecker-Weber, every abelian extension of $\mathbf Q$ is contained in a cyclotomic extension. If $H/\mathbf Q$ were abelian, we would have $\mathbf Q(\zeta_q) \subseteq H \subseteq \mathbf Q(\zeta_n)$ for some $n$; then, examining the ramification, we see that $n=q$ and so $H=\mathbf Q(\zeta_q)$.

The degree of $H/\mathbf Q$ is equal to $q-1$ times the class number $h_q$.

In general, the primes which split completely in the Hilbert class field are those which are principal in the base field.

The class group of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_n)$ is a very complicated thing. Whole books are devoted to it. It is a fascinating topic with deep connections to the theory of the Riemann zeta function.

I recommend Washington's book *Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields*. If you are interested specifically in Iwasawa theory, I would recommend the book *Cyclotomic Fields and Zeta Values* by Coates and Sujatha, which is a great introduction to this truly unbelievable theory.

Comment: Ah, Kronecker-Weber, good point! If that's the case, is there any way to characterize the set of primes $p$ that splits completely in $H$, using only arithmetic data of the ground field?

Comment: Dear @Sanchez: I have edited my answer to answer this.

Comment: Thanks! I know this (actually that's how I came up with the question). I meant to characterize the set of primes in $\mathbb{Q}$, that splits completely in $H$ (the Hilbert class field of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_q)$ in this case, not necessarily abelian like you said) in a way similar to class field theory. I know that congruence conditions won't be possible here, but what can I say in general?

Comment: @Sanchez Ah, I see. Then I don't know. I don't think that there is a simple criterion.

Comment: Thanks! This should really be a new question, but here it goes anyway: What would non-abelian reciprocity law tell us in this case (characterizing the set of completely splitting primes in $H$)? It's not congruence conditions on $p$, but what kind of condition would it be?

Comment: @Sanchez Well, such a condition would reduce to identifying explicitly the automorphic representations associated by the Langlands conjectures to the irreducible representations of Gal(H/Q). If you're lucky, they will come from familiar objects, and you might be able to write something down.

Answer (score 6):

Take the $ p^{\text{th}} $ cyclotomic ring of integers, the homomorphism $ \sigma:\zeta\to\zeta^\gamma $ with some primitive root $ \gamma $ modulo $ p $. Circle divisions and the drawing of regular polygons was very popular in $ 19^{\text{th}} $ century mathematics. Many great names are attached to it. Jacobi (and independently Gauss and Cauchy) found the cyclotomic integer $ \omega_{q,i}(\zeta) $, $ q\equiv1\pmod{p} $, the so-called Jacobi cyclotomic  function, that only factorizes to prime ideals lying over the prime $ q $ and that factorizes either to the prime ideal $ \langle q,\sigma^j\psi_q(\zeta)\rangle $ or the prime ideal $ \langle q,\sigma^{j+\mu}\psi_q(\zeta)\rangle $ with $ \mu=(p-1)/2 $ but it does not factorize to both. We only note here that the second generator $ \psi_q(\zeta) $ of the prime ideal $ \langle q,\sigma^j\psi_q(\zeta)\rangle $ was found by Kummer. Kummer had the idea of choosing exponents $ z_i\in\mathbb{Z} $ such that
\begin{equation*}
\left\lbrace q\cdot\dfrac{\langle q,\sigma^0\psi_q(\zeta)\rangle}{\langle q,\sigma^{\mu}\psi_q(\zeta)\rangle}\right\rbrace^{h_0}=\left\langle\prod_i\omega_{q,i}^{z_i}(\zeta)\right\rangle,\quad h_0\in\mathbb{N}_0.
\end{equation*}
If the prime ideal $ \langle q,\sigma^0\psi_q(\zeta)\rangle $ is principal, there exists a cyclotomic integer $ g(\zeta) $ such that
\begin{equation*}
\left\langle g(\zeta)\right\rangle=q\cdot\dfrac{\langle q,\sigma^0\psi_q(\zeta)\rangle}{\langle q,\sigma^{\mu}\psi_q(\zeta)\rangle}
\end{equation*}
with $ \langle q,\sigma^{\mu}\psi_q(\zeta)\rangle\mid \langle q\rangle $ and there exists a unit $ \varepsilon $ such that
\begin{equation*}
\varepsilon\cdot g^{h_0}(\zeta)=\prod_i\omega_{q,i}^{z_i}(\zeta).
\end{equation*}
Kummer could compute this unit to $ \varepsilon=(-\zeta)^k $ with some integer $ k $. We apply another method of Kummer, that he used in order to prove that the class number of the  $37^{\text{th}} $ **real** cyclotomic ring of integers is not divisible by the prime $ p=37 $, and take the power of $ n $ such that $ (-\zeta)^{kn}=1 $ and $ h_0n=r-1 $ hold for some prime $ r\equiv1\pmod{p} $. By group theory we have
\begin{equation*}
\left\lbrace (-\zeta)^k\cdot g^{h_0}(\zeta)\right\rbrace^n=g^{h_0n}(\zeta)=g^{r-1}(\zeta)\equiv1\pmod{\langle r,\sigma^j\psi_r(\zeta)\rangle}
\end{equation*}
for any conjugate prime ideal $ \langle r,\sigma^j\psi_r(\zeta)\rangle $ in the multiplicative group of the quotient field $ \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta]}/\langle r,\sigma^j\psi_r(\zeta)\rangle $ with order $ r-1 $. Now, if
\begin{equation*}
\left\lbrace\prod_i\omega_{q,i}^{z_i}(\zeta)\right\rbrace^n\not\equiv1\pmod{\langle r,\sigma^j\psi_r(\zeta)\rangle}
\end{equation*}
the prime ideal $ \langle q,\sigma^j\psi_q(\zeta)\rangle $ cannot be principal.

Now take the $37^{\text{th}}$ cyclotomic ring of integers, the homomorphism $\sigma:\zeta\to\zeta^2$ with the primitive root $2$ modulo $37$. Incongruence is given for $ h_0=37 $, $ q=149 $, $ r=5477=4\cdot37^2+1 $ and every conjugate prime ideal $ \langle r,\sigma^j\psi_r(\zeta)\rangle $, thus, the prime ideals lying over the prime $ 149 $ are not principal. Kummer's class number formula gives for the first factor $ 37 $ and the second factor can be determined to $ 1 $ by the Minkowski bound in the **real** cyclotomic ring of integers, thus, the prime ideals lying over the prime $ 149 $ have class order $ 37 $.

Now take the cylotomic integer $g(\zeta)=-\zeta^{13}+\zeta^{25}+\zeta^{27}+\zeta^{30}+\zeta^{32}$ in the $37^{\text{th}}$ cyclotomic ring of integers. The ideal $\langle g(\zeta)\rangle$ factorizes to $\langle g(\zeta)\rangle=\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle^{2}\cdot\langle149, \sigma^{11}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle$. The cyclotomic integer $$h(\zeta)=\zeta-\zeta^{4}-\zeta^{7}-\zeta^{8}-\zeta^{9}-\zeta^{11}-\zeta^{12}-\zeta^{13}-\zeta^{14}-\zeta^{15}+\zeta^{16}-\zeta^{18}-\zeta^{19}+\zeta^{21}-\zeta^{22}-\zeta^{23}-\zeta^{24}-\zeta^{25}-\zeta^{26}-\zeta^{28}-\zeta^{29}-\zeta^{30}-\zeta^{33}+\zeta^{36}$$ factorizes to $\langle h(\zeta)\rangle=\langle149, \sigma^{11}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle\cdot\langle149, \sigma^{29}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle$. The two factorizations give the class equivalence $\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle^{2}\sim\langle149, \sigma^{29}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle$. We square this equivalence and get

$${\left\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\right\rangle^{4}}\sim\left\{\left\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\right\rangle^{2}\right\}^2\sim
{\left\langle149, \sigma^{29}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\right\rangle^2}\sim
{\sigma^{29}\circ\left\langle149, \sigma^{29}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\right\rangle}\sim
{\left\langle149, \sigma^{2\cdot29}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\right\rangle}.$$

Consecutively squaring gives

$$\tag{1}\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle^{2^k}\sim\langle149, \sigma^{29k}\psi_{149}(\zeta).$$

With $\sigma^{36}=\sigma^0\equiv\text{id}$ we get $\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle^{2^{36}}\sim\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)$. We take the letter $ I $ for the principal class and finally obtain $\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle^{2^{36}-1}\sim I$. Therefore the class order of the prime ideal $\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle$ divides the integer $2^{36}-1$.

Now we take the cyclotomic integer $s(\zeta)=\zeta-\zeta^{4}-\zeta^{17}+\zeta^{25}-\zeta^{27}-\zeta^{34}$. It factorizes to $\langle s(\zeta)\rangle=\langle149, \sigma^{12}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle\cdot\langle149, \sigma^{26}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle\cdot\langle149, \sigma^{27}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle$. With $24\cdot29\equiv12\pmod{36}$ we first get $\sigma^{24\cdot29}=\sigma^{12}$ and equivalence ($1$) gives the equivalence $\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle^{2^{24}}\sim\langle149, \sigma^{12}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle$. Similarly we get $\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle^{2^{22}}\sim\langle149, \sigma^{26}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle$ and $\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle^{2^{27}}\sim\langle149, \sigma^{27}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle$. This yields

$${\left\langle149, \sigma^{12}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\right\rangle\cdot\left\langle149, \sigma^{26}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\right\rangle\cdot\left\langle149, \sigma^{27}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\right\rangle}\sim
{\left\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\right\rangle^{2^{24}}\cdot\left\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\right\rangle^{2^{22}}\cdot\left\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\right\rangle^{2^{27}}}\sim 
{\left\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\right\rangle^{2^{24}+2^{22}+2^{27}}}\sim I.$$

Hence the class order of the prime ideal $\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle$ divides the integer $2^{24} + 2^{22} + 2^{27}$. But then the class order of the prime ideal $\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle$ divides the greatest common divisor $\gcd (2^{36}-1, 2^{24} + 2^{22} + 2^{27}) = 37$. Kummer's class number formula is $37$ so that we have confirmed this class order by the factorization of cyclotomic integers! We finally get $\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle^{2^{5}}\sim\langle149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle^{32}\sim\langle149, \sigma\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle$ with $5\cdot29\equiv1\pmod{36}$. The integer $\xi=2^5=32$ is a primitive root modulo $37$. Therefore there are $36$ prime ideals

$$\tag{2}\sigma^n\left\langle149, \sigma^0\psi_{149}(\zeta)\right\rangle=\left\langle149, \sigma^n\psi_{149}(\zeta)\right\rangle\sim\left\langle149, \sigma^0\psi_{149}(\zeta)\right\rangle^{32^{n}},\quad n=0,\dots,35,$$

and each occupies a different class of the $36$ non-principal classes.

The exponent $f$ of a prime $q$ modulo the prime $p$ is the least positive integer $f$ such that $q^f\equiv1 \pmod{p}$. This  is also the order $ f=\text{ord}\,q\pmod{p} $. Kummer already knew that a prime $q$ with exponent $f$ modulo $p$ factorizes to $e=\frac{p-1}{f}$ prime ideals $\langle q, \sigma^k\psi_{q}(\zeta)\rangle$,$0\le k<e$, with $\langle q, \sigma^k\psi_{q}(\zeta)\rangle=\langle q, \sigma^{k+e}\psi_{q}(\zeta)\rangle$. Then all prime ideals lying over a prime $q$ with an exponent $f>1$ must be principal because otherwise the homomorphisms $\sigma^0,\sigma^e,\sigma^{2e},\dots,\sigma^{e(f-1)}$ would send the prime ideal

$${\left\langle q, \sigma^{0e}\psi_{q}(\zeta)\right\rangle}=
{\left\langle q, \sigma^{e}\psi_{q}(\zeta)\right\rangle}=
{\left\langle q, \sigma^{2e}\psi_{q}(\zeta)\right\rangle}=\dots=
{\left\langle q, \sigma^{(f-1)e}\psi_{q}(\zeta)\right\rangle}$$

to distinct classes because

- the prime ideal $ \langle q, \sigma^{0e}\psi_{q}(\zeta)\rangle $ must be in the same class of one of the $ 36 $ conjugate prime ideal $ \langle149, \sigma^{j}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle $, $ j=0,\dots,35 $, and
- the prime ideals $ \langle149, \sigma^{j}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle $, $ \langle149, \sigma^{j+e}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle $ are in different classes.

Therefore only prime ideals lying over a prime q with order $f=1$ can be non-principal. If a prime ideal is not principal one conjugate prime ideal $\langle q, \sigma^{k}\psi_{q}(\zeta)\rangle$ must be equivalent to the prime ideal $\langle 149, \sigma^{0}\psi_{149}(\zeta)\rangle$ and the class group is well understood.

A detailed approach to these mysterious determinants $ h_0 $, as Kummer and Gauss put it, can be taken from section $ 6.10 $, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12qJd-VxzCKA_cuvG0Un0WUS97HSKpnJu/view?usp=sharing). Chapter $ 21 $ contains the class groups of all $ p^{\text{th}} $ cyclotomic rings of integers for odd primes $ p\leq71 $.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/717146)

Comment: Please consider joining your two accounts, doing so makes housekeeping easier for everybody.

Comment: I think something is wrong here. Let $\pi$ be your ideal dividing $149$. You compute that $\sigma(\pi) \equiv \pi^{29}$. I compute that $29 \equiv 2^{21} \bmod 37$, and the class group is cyclic of order $37$, so we have $\sigma(\pi) \equiv \pi^{2^{21}}$. This should imply that, if $\sigma_a$ is the Galois automorphism with $\sigma_a(\zeta) = \zeta^a$, then $\sigma_a(\pi) \equiv \pi^{a^{21}}$. But $10^3 \equiv 1 \bmod 37$, so $10^{21} \equiv 1 \bmod 37$, so $\sigma_{10}$ should fix $\pi$, and only $12$ of the $36$ nontrivial classes should be in the Galois orbit of $I$.

Comment: Specifically, I am diagreeing with your claim that each of the $36$ ideals $\sigma^k(\pi)$ are distinct in the class group. I agree that they are distinct ideals, but I think they only occupy $12$ of the $36$ nontrivial classes.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer For $ k=5 $ we get equivalence $ (2) $ with $ n=1 $ from  equivalence $ (1) $ or $ \sigma(\pi)\equiv\pi^{32} $ with your notation.

Comment: I read this answer a few years ago. Nothing remained in my mind. But, I am curious about the answer.