# When are the integers extended with the nth root of unity a unique factorization domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring, roots-of-unity, unique-factorization-domains

Let $\zeta_n$ be the $n$th [root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).  The wikipedia page for [unique factorization domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) (UFD) states that for $n \in \mathbb Z$, $1 \le n \le 22$, $\mathbb Z[\zeta_n]$ is a UFD, but not for $n = 23$.  Is there a general formula for determining when an integer extension with a root of unity is a UFD?  Failing that, is it known for higher $n$ than $23$?

Comment: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field#List_of_class_numbers_of_cyclotomic_fields) may be of interest.

Comment: Ah, so only $n$ with class number 1 is a UFD, correct?  Thanks for the link!  I haven't yet been able to find how a class number is calculated.  Really interesting history about Kummer's work and Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585260/what-do-we-know-about-the-class-group-of-cyclotomic-fields-over-mathbbq?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496320/when-is-bbbz-zeta-n-a-pid).

Comment: Note that it is UFD if and only it is PID.

Comment: Oops! Sorry for asking a duplicate.  That question didn't come up when I searched, but it is clearly the same.  Should I delete my question?

Comment: Don't worry, just leave it. It might be of help to somebody else who's searching for the same thing.