# $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is a euclidean ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to prove, that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ with 
$\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ is an euclidean ring with
$N(a+b\alpha)=|a+b\alpha|^2$.

So far I have shown that $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$ and therefore $N(x)\leq N(xy)$ $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

But now I am stuck with the euclidean division: I want to calculate
$$\frac{a+b\alpha}{c+d\alpha}$$ where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ in order to find the $q,r\in\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

Can someone help me to calculate the above fraction?

I would be grateful for any kind of help or advice!

Thank you.

Comment: This is $\Bbb Z[\zeta_3]$, which is Euclidean, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2434662/when-are-the-integers-extended-with-the-nth-root-of-unity-a-unique-factorization?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: try multiplying top and bottom by $c+d\bar\alpha $ (complex conjugate of $\alpha$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $N(x+y\alpha)=(x+y\alpha)(x+y\bar\alpha)$.