# Showing that $\mathbf{Z}$ adjoin a primitive seventh root of unity is a UFD.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

What I have done so far is first note this is the ring of integers over the seventh cyclotomic field. This has degree 6 and only complex embeddings. Then I computed minkowskis bound to be around 4.4.

Now we only have to examine (2) and (3) . I want to use dedekind here and I factored $X^6+...+1$ into two irreducible cubic over $\mathbf{F}_2 $ but I am unsure on showing these are principal and I am not sure how to factor over $\mathbf{F}_3 $.

Could someone give me a hint on how to proceed? Thanks

Comment: The class number of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_7)$ is equal to $1$, see the answers in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585260/what-do-we-know-about-the-class-group-of-cyclotomic-fields-over-mathbbq), for example.

Comment: aha! thanks @The Phoenix . I think I had gotten used to computing class groups for quadratic fields that I wasnt thinking about mikowskis bound in this way. Makes perfect sense. Not sure how to accept this as an answer.